# Android unsupported operation exception fileoutputstream?

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

I would to read a file from raw folder and write it on SD card.I use this code:

```
byte buf[] = new byte[1000000];
int readLen = 0;

InputStream resStream = context.getResources()
.openRawResource(R.raw.diction_index);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(indexFile);

while ((readLen = resStream.read(buf)) > 0)
os.write(buf, 0, readLen);

os.close();
resStream.close();
```

When I use `API level 5` ,I get this error in run time(in `OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(indexFile);` ) ,and when I use upper API levels,every thing is good.How I can solve this problem?What causes this problem?

Comment: what's indexFile? All the FileOuptStream API si avilable since the first release. So it does not make sense

Comment: @blackbelt File indexFile = new File(basePath + "/diction.index");

Comment: Please since File has constructors that takes more pamarmeter is better to use it instead of creating a temporary string to pass at the File constructor. Take a look to the doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: @blackbelt Do you think this can be different in different API s ?And please tell me generally in about this run time error.

Comment: No, since in the snipet you post no method call throws UnsupportedOperationExecption.